# Delphi 10: What can I do about String[25] changing some char values to "?"

Tags: delphi, encryption, delphi-7, delphi-xe

I have ported a Delphi 7.1 application to Delphi 10.3.
I have some simple encrypting/decryption functions.
And if I encrypt string values and encrypt them, everything is fine:

```
var
   test, encrypted, decrypted : string;
begin
  test := 'XXXXXXXX'; // hidden message 
  encrypted := _common.encrypt(test);
  decrypted := _common.decrypt(encrypted );  
end;
```

in this scenario, everything works as expected, even with special characters, encrypted would be: 'y'#$0080'vn'

but if the value is of string[25], it handles special characters differently:

```
var
   test,decrypted : string;
   encrypted : string[25]
begin
  test := 'XXXXXXXX'; // hidden message 
  encrypted := _common.encrypt(test);
  decrypted := _common.decrypt(encrypted);  
end;
```

in this scenario, everything work as expected unless the encrypted string contains special characters in this example res1 would be: 'y?vn'

I'm using string[] in records, when writing/reading data to/from disk

How can I fix this?

Can I use a different string type for the record type, or ?

/Flemming

Comment: You should return bytes when you encrypt, not a string.

Comment: `string[25]` is a `ShortString`, but `string` is `UnicodeString`, so you are invoking a Unicode->ANSI conversion that can lose non-ASCII characters > $7F, which is exactly what you are seeing happen.

Comment: [Delphi and Unicode](https://edn.embarcadero.com/article/images/38980/Delphi_and_Unicode.pdf) - everything you need to know.

Comment: My problem is that I have stored data with the old encryption which I have to read, so I have to use an array of string, but a normal string not a short string. 
Is there some other way to set a fixed size array of string for 255 byte characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Delphi 7, the `string` type has changed from one-byte ANSI characters to two-byte Unicode characters. However, the fixed-length `string[n]` still is a one-byte ANSI string. Therefore, you are mixing different string types. The easiest fix might be to switch those variables which you declare as `string` to a declaration as `AnsiString` instead.

Comment: I understand, but I need to support legacy data, so how can fix this string[xx] being a shortstring where I lose non-ASCII characters > $7F,

What can I use as a fixed string array instead of string[25] ... because I need to be able  read the old formatted data.

Comment: If you really have two byte characters you should either use a string without fixed length or you could use an array [0..24] of char, since char is two-byte, now.

Comment: How do I save a string to an array[0..24] of char?

Comment: StrpLCopy(destarray,sourcestring,25);

Comment: Using StrpLCopy gives this compiler error:
[dcc32 Error] mzm_common.pas(1759): E2010 Incompatible types: 'array[0..24] of Char' and 'PWideChar'

Comment: Do not assign the function result to the array. You can disregard the function result and use the function like it was a procedure. Do exactly as in my comment before. The result is correctly saved into the destarray variable. Works for me in Delphi 10.0 and Delphi 10.3

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you don't get same results in both code examples is that first code example fully relies on using default string type which in Delphi 10.3 is WideString (two bytes per character).

But in your second code example you declare your result as `string[25]` which is a short string type. Now unlike regular string type ShortString type can only contain single byte characters or in other word only supports AnsiString type which was default string type in Delphi 7.

So you don't get teh same results as you are mixing two different string types.

---

Any way general rule when dealing with encryption and decryption is not to work with strings at all but instead work with raw binary data. Why?

At the time of Delphi 7 strings have been affected by the currently used string encoding. So if you encrypted some string on a computer that used one string encoding and decrypted on a computer that used another string encoding you would get wrong result.

Now on modern Delphi versions that use WideString with Unicode encoding this no longer pose such problem but there is another potential problem since on Windows strings are 1 based (index of first character in string is 1) while on mobile platforms strings are 0 based (index of first character is 0).

So I strongly recommend you redesign your encryption/decryption routines to work on raw binary data instead.

Comment: "*default string type which in Delphi 10.3 is WideString*" - since Delphi 2009, the default string type is `UnicodeString`, not `WideString`.  They are both UTF-16 encoded strings, but they have very different management requirements (`UnicodeString` is reference-counted and allocated with the Delphi Memory Manager, whereas `WideString` is not reference-counted and is allocated with the COM memory manager).

Comment: From 10.4, the default index of strings starts at 1 in both Desktop and Mobile compilers. From http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Zero-based_strings_(Delphi) : _Note: Previous to Delphi 10.4 the mobile compilers used by default 0-based indexing for strings._